# How do I get my site images to properly load within LowCodeUnit?

Tags: github

When using LowCodeUnit, after 'Unpacking Latest' and syncing with GitHub and going to my lowcodeunit.com site, some of the images on my site are not showing up as desired.

Comment: Please specify how exactly the images are showing differently from what you have desired. We don't know your desires :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently LowCodeUnit only supports file paths (and file names) without spaces. Also, entire file paths are case-sensitive (including file extensions).  If needed, there is a great free MS tool for batch renaming of files on Windows called PowerRename that you can download here:

https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/releases/